# How to dim an empty array of a specific length

Tags: arrays, powershell

I need to copy a collection of 10 items into an array so I can index into it. So I need to use the `CopyTo` method and specify a destination array large enough to accommodate the collection.

So before calling `CopyTo` I need to dim an empty array of a specific size. I can't seem to find the correct PowerShell syntax for doing this.

This didn't work for me:

```
$snapshot = New-Object System.Array 10;
```

> New-Object : Constructor not found. Cannot find an appropriate constructor for type System.Array.

**Edit**

Have worked around it with:

```
$snapshot = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList;
$snapshot.AddRange($slider);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [PowerShell array initialization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226596/powershell-array-initialization)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should do the trick:

```
$snapshot = @()
```

Edit: 
Ok, sorry about that.
Tested this one:

```
> $snapshot  = New-Object object[] 10
> $snapshot.Length 
10
```

Comment: Sadly not. It's size 0.

Answer (score 0):

I think just creating a new array will accomplish that in Powershell.

```
# A "collection of ten items"
$collection = @(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0)

#This command creates a new array, sizes it, and copies data into the new array
$newCollection = $collection
```

Powershell creates a new array in this case. No need to specify the size of the array; Powershell sizes it automatically. And if you add an element to the array, Powershell will take care of the tedious initializeNew-copy-deleteOld routine you have to do in lower-level languages.

Note that $newCollection isn't a reference to the same array that $collection references. It's a reference to a whole new array. Modifying $collection won't affect $newCollection, and vice-versa.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not address my needs. I need an empty array of a specific length. I'm working with custom collection types from a .NET library rather than purely manipulating PS arrays.