# How to create an empty array with specific number of cells in PowerShell?

Tags: arrays, powershell

I want to define an array which will contain 100 empty cells . So far I did it in this way :

```
$EntryAmount = New-Object 'double[]' 100
```

It seems to be working, but I'm not sure it's the right way. From all of the examples that I've seen, there was a definition for empty arrays without actual size or with specific content which then defined the size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To create the array:-**

```
[double[]] $EntryAmount = @($null)*100
```

**To populate the array:-**

```
$EntryAmount[0] = 50.35
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is -

```
$EntryAmount = @(0) * 100
```

**OR**

```
$EntryAmount =,0 * 100
```

See [*this*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/226596/powershell-array-initialization) link for more such ways of defining an array.